# ACC - Get Projects Archived

Tags: autodesk-data-management

is it possible to get HUB's archived projects with Data Management API's?

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-GET/

I also tried with BIM360 API's but it lists only active projects

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-GET/

It sounds strange because in the property "status" in the body response seems to be expected

[image]

TIA
Alder

Comment: I'm checking with our engineering team and will update here once they reply to me.

Comment: @EasonKang, do you have any news about this topic?

Comment: Sorry for missing here. Unfortunately, the current API design doesn't support filtering archived projects according to our engineering team.